# Framed theorem environment spread across pages

Tags: page-breaking, theorems, framed, mdframed, amsthm

I wanted to put a vertical line in front of examples to make them easier to distinguish from the regular text. For this I used mdframed, and it mostly seems to work. However, if an example happens to be close to the bottom of the page (so that it doesn't quite fit anymore), instead of having part of it at the bottom of the page and part of it on the next page, the bottom part of the page simply isn't used, *part* of the example is on the next page (the rest of that page is blank), and the rest of the example is on the page after that... Any suggestions for solving this would be very welcome.

Code:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\surroundwithmdframed[bottomline=false,topline=false,rightline=false,
    linewidth=1pt,
    skipabove=0,
    skipbelow=0,
    innertopmargin=-\topsep,
    innerbottommargin=0]{example}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\begin{example}
\blindtext
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should probably have a look at [`thmbox`](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/thmbox/)

Comment: Interesting suggestion (although it looks like it won't do exactly what I need it to do). However, it turns out the problem is in using `-\topsep`. I have now managed to work around the problem by redefining the style for the example environment to not have any spacing above and below, and instead add that spacing using mdframed. This appears to work, but I would still be interested in knowing a bit more about _why_ using a negative value here leads to this particular (fairly weird) bug.

Comment: I have absolutely no hint on the cause of this behavior.

Comment: Negative inner top margin is certainly among "undocumented behaviours" w.r.t. page breaking. Without showing your new code, we can't really help you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved by the OP in comments.

Comment: @Jasper -- the question you ask in a comment about why `-\topsep` is causing a problem would be reasonable as a new question, pointing to this one.